# CSS hover over wide

Tags: css, hover

Current my mouse pointer if there is point out of the red colour box it still doing the hover function, but what i need is i only need the hover in red colour box, it out of the box it will hide the menu.

This is the my source from JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KECN7/

This is my html source code

```
     <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="btn-function"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="' . wp_logout_url(home_url()) . '">Logout</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms & Policies</a></li>           
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

this is css source code

```
#menu{
        /*width: 50%;*/
        margin: 0;
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        list-style: none;   
        position: absolute;
}

#menu li{
        float: left;
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
        position: relative;

}

#menu a{
        float: left;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 0 25px;
        color: #999;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a{
        color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover{ /* IE6 */
        color: #fafafa;
}

#menu li:hover > ul{
        display: block;
    z-index: 99;    
}

/* Sub-menu */

#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 10px 0 25px 0;
    /*width: 50px;*/
    padding: 0;    
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 10px;
    z-index: 99999;    
    background: #444;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);    
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#menu ul li{

    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
}

#menu ul li:last-child{   
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#menu ul a{    
    padding: 15px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

*html #menu ul a{ /* IE6 */   
        height: 10px;
        width: 150px;
}

*:first-child+html #menu ul a{ /* IE7 */    
        height: 10px;
        width: 150px;
}

#menu ul a:hover{
        background: #0186ba;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);    
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
        background: linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
}

#menu ul li:first-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after{
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

#menu ul li:last-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after{
        visibility: hidden;
        display: block;
        font-size: 0;
        content: " ";
        clear: both;
        height: 0;
}

a.btn-function {
    background-image: url(../ovolo/img/btn_function.png); 
    background-color: red;
    background-size: 27px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    position: relative;    
    margin: 0px 5px 0 90px;
    float: left;   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are applying the red box to the `a` element, but taking action on the (larger) `li` parent element.

You can change your selector to ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KECN7/5/)):

```
#menu li a:hover + ul, #menu li a + ul:hover{
    display: block;
    z-index: 99;    
}
```

This is not a perfect fix because of the dead space between the `a` and the `ul` though, the best option would be to make the `a` take up the entire space of the `li`.

Comment: It was able to do it but when the mouse go to the dropdown menu, sometime it was able to select, sometime it can't. It must go over the triangle shape icon it only able to do the select.

Comment: to ensure that avoid top: or margin ..use padding instead

Comment: @RitabrataGautam May I know which part am going to use padding instead to use margin?